# Multiple clients issue on C# TCP

Tags: c#, multithreading, client, tcpclient

I'm kind of new to this ask-answer thing, please let me know if I've done any mistakes. I have this server program, running on my laptop. Server is a console application;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server sv = new Server("192.168.2.69", 52025);
        sv.OnClientAccept += new ClientAcceptHandler(sv_OnClientAccept);
        sv.OnClientMessage += new ClientMessageHandler(sv_OnClientMessage);
        sv.Start();
    }

    static void sv_OnClientMessage(Server s, System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message received from client " + GetClientIp(client) + ": \"" + message + "\"");
        string msgToAll = message;
        s.SendToAllClients(msgToAll);
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent: \"" + message + "\" to the clients:");
        foreach (TcpClient cl in s.Clients)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetClientIp(cl));
        }
    }

    static void sv_OnClientAccept(Server s, System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client Accepted : " + GetClientIp(client));
    }

    static string GetClientIp(TcpClient Client)
    {
        return ((IPEndPoint)Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
    }

}
```

The Server class;

```
public delegate void ClientAcceptHandler(Server s, TcpClient client);

public delegate void ClientMessageHandler(Server s, TcpClient client, string message);

public class Server
{

    private List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();

    object lockObjc;

    private TcpListener server;

    private string ip;

    private int port;

    private Thread accepter, listener;



    public List<TcpClient> Clients { get { return this.clients; } set { this.clients = value; } }

    public event ClientAcceptHandler OnClientAccept;

    public event ClientMessageHandler OnClientMessage;



    public Server(string IP, int Port)
    {
        ip = IP;
        port = Port;
    }

    private void ClientAccepted(TcpClient Client)
    {
        if (OnClientAccept != null)
        {
            OnClientAccept.Invoke(this, Client);
        }
    }

    private void ClientMessaged(TcpClient Client, string Message)
    {
        if (OnClientMessage != null)
        {
            OnClientMessage.Invoke(this, Client, Message);
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        lockObjc = new object();
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);//127.0.0.1 -> local || "192.168.2.69" -> laptop
        server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);//2014 -> local || 52025
        server.Start();

        accepter = new Thread(AcceptClients);
        accepter.Start();

        listener = new Thread(Listen);
        listener.Start();
    }

    private void AcceptClients()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient attachedCl = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (attachedCl != null)
            {
                lock (lockObjc)
                {
                    if (!clients.Contains(attachedCl))
                    {
                        clients.Add(attachedCl);
                        ClientAccepted(attachedCl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
            {
                TcpClient client = clients[i];
                lock (lockObjc)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        StreamReader clientIn = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                        string msg = clientIn.ReadLine();
                        if (msg != string.Empty)
                        {
                            ClientMessaged(client, msg);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool send(TcpClient Client, string Msg)
    {
        bool b = true;
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = Client;
            StreamWriter clientOut = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            clientOut.AutoFlush = true;
            clientOut.WriteLine(Msg);
        }
        catch
        {
            b = false;
        }
        return b;
    }



    public bool SendToACLient(TcpClient Client, string Message)
    {
        return send(Client, Message);
    }

    public bool SendToAClient(int i, string Message)
    {
        return send(clients[i], Message);
    }

    public bool SendToAllClients(string Message)
    {
        bool b = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        {
            b = b && send(clients[i], Message);
        }
        return b;
    }

    public bool SendToAllClientsExcept(TcpClient Client, string Message)
    {
        int x = clients.IndexOf(Client);
        bool b = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != x)
            {
                b = b && send(clients[i], Message);
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

}
```

Since I'm really new to server-client relationships, I don't know if the server part is OK, but it seems OK to me programmatically (But I'm also amateur programer, no real education).

And the client part is;

```
public delegate void ServerMessageHandler(Client Receiver, string Message);

public class Client
{

    private StreamReader clientIn;

    private StreamWriter clientOut;

    private TcpClient client;

    private Thread listener;

    private object lockObj;



    public event ServerMessageHandler OnServerMessage;

    public bool Connected { get { return (client != null && client.Connected); } }



    public Client()
    {
        lockObj = new object();

        client = new TcpClient();

        listener = new Thread(Listen);
    }



    private void ServerMessaged(string Message)
    {
        if (OnServerMessage != null)
        {
            OnServerMessage.Invoke(this, Message);
        }
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        string serverMsg;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                serverMsg = clientIn.ReadLine();
                if (serverMsg != string.Empty)
                {
                    ServerMessaged(serverMsg);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void start()
    {
        listener.Start();
    }



    public bool Connect(string Ip, int Port)
    {
        client.Connect(Ip, Port);//"192.168.2.69", 52025
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            clientIn = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            clientOut = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            clientOut.AutoFlush = true;

            start();

        }
        return client.Connected;
    }

    public void Send(string Message)
    {
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            clientOut.WriteLine(Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the form that I run Client class;

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string s;
    Client c;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = new Client();
        c.OnServerMessage += new ServerMessageHandler(c_OnServerMessage);
        bool b = c.Connect("192.168.2.69", 52025);
        if (b)
        {
            s += "Connected to the server: 192.168.2.69:52025\r\n";
        }
        timer1.Start();
    }

    void c_OnServerMessage(Client Receiver, string Message)
    {
        s += "Server: " + Message + "\r\n";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c.Send(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = s;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            c.Send(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

This form has two textboxes, first one is the one which takes user input (`textBox1`), the second one is the one which shows server responds. Why I'm not using `Console`? Because I've tried it in a way which I was waiting an input from user (`Console.ReadLine`) which as far as I know locks the console until user presses enter, even tough I'm using a thread for listening the server, I wasn't able to show the server answer on console.

So, I decided to create my own console (sort-of). The reason I run a timer to show messages is I get an error when I try to change the textbox text from a method that is being called by a thread (which is the `c_OnServerMessage` method, being called, indirectly, from the Listener thread from Client class)

But the problem I get here is this: I run the server on my laptop, I also run one client on my laptop which goes perfectly fine until I open up another client on another computer. At that point things go this way: I send a message from a client, the message reaches the server and is sent back. When I send another message, that message does not reach the server until I send a message from Client 2. And when I send a message from Client 2, the server gets the message from Client 2 even tough I sent the message from Client 1 first.

So basically what happens is, if I run 2 clients, I cannot send 2 messages in a row from a client, it kind of acts like a chess game where there is a turn for playing. I really don't understand the reason.

This problem is probably from a basic mistake but I had to write this whole message to be able to express myself. Thank you for your patient and your helps.

EDIT:
Problem solved thanks to this: [TCP server with multiple Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218589/tcp-server-with-multiple-clients)
My problem was the Listen method from Server class. The Listen method is being called by a thread, but still it runs a for loop in itself. Which if loop stops and waits for something, thread wouldn't make any difference. Thanks again, i think i will keep question, because i do not know what should happen to solved problems.

Comment: Please write Question first. Not clear to me after 5 screens of text

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the locking you've got. You've got a lot of threads locking on a single object, but it's not at all clear why.